# Как работают Service в ОС Android?

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-service

Мне не совсем понятны некоторые моменты реализации `Service` в ОС Android:

1. Я стартую `Service`, в котором есть поле `private int depCount;`. В процессе работы `Service` оно меняется. `Service` я останавливаю методом `stopService()`. Когда я заново стартую его, поле `depCount` уже не нулевое - оно принимает то значение, которое было перед предыдущей остановкой `Service`. Почему так происходит?
2. Если я вызову метод `startService()` для одного `Service` несколько раз подряд, то он будет запущен всего один раз, правильно?

Answer (score 5):

1. Посмотрите [урок](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/157-urok-92-service-prostoj-primer.html) там хорошо рассказывают о `Service`. Переменная `depCount` показывает как себя вести, если `Service` убит.
2. Да, он будет всего один раз запущен, пока `Service` не будет остановлен или убит.

Comment: Со вторым понятно, спасибо. А вот с первым я не понял..почему переменная depCount инициализируется нулем только при первом запуске сервиса, а при последующих она каким-то образом принимает предыдущие значения.

Comment: Потому что он еще ни разу не был остановлен. Нужно же чередовать когда сервис запущен/остановлен. Сервисы работают в фоне, т.е. не зависимо от активности(можно выйти из приложения и сервис  все равно будет работать). При старте активности которая стартует сервис, сервис смотрит значение переменной и определяет текущее положене.

Comment: Нет, я его останавливаю, потом запускаю еще раз...но только что я понял - дело не в сервисе, переменная инициализируется как надо. Дело в методе onLocationChanged. Сервис служит для обновления координат и переменная depCount используется в методе onLocationChanged. Там она изменяется, а при следующим запуске она хоть и инициализируется нульом снова, но в методе onLocationChanged каждый раз значения будет взято с предыдущего раза..Не знаю почему так, буду разбираться. Спасибо.